# Переход от C# к C++ и C

Tags: c#, c, c++

Когда то давно я, разумеется, как и все изучал C, C++, Pascal, однако потом перешёл на C# и Java и работал с ними в течении долгого времени. В результате получилось что я знаю последние очень хорошо, а особенности C и C++ забыл чуть менее чем полностью. Подскажите как проще всего восстановить знания, не начиная изучать всё сначала?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если все-таки что-то знаете, можно взять какую-нибудь книжку типа "C++ in depth" и разбираться. Так многое само собой вспомниться.

Можно взяться изучать вглубь STL и какие-нибудь библиотеки из Boost. Если будет встречаться что-то непонятное, обращаться к элементарным учебникам. Какие-то разделы, которые забыли или пропустили в свое время, подучить целиком.

И параллельно писать проект, пусть небольшой, на С++. Стараться применять при этом новые знания.

Comment: согласен, если приведёте примеры таких книг "C++ in depth" - зачту ответ

Comment: Джосьютис (он же Джосаттис - Josuttis) "С++. Стандартная библиотека". Вандервуд, Джосаттис "Шаблоны С++". Мейерс "Эффективный С++". Страуструпа хорошо почитать. Потом Александреску.

Comment: Через пару месяцес должно выйти новое издание "Стандартной библиотеки" Джосаттиса. Жду не дождусь.

Comment: есть такая книжка "С++ за 21 день" я лично по ней изучал с++ и остался очень доволен доволен (скачал на рутрекере)

Answer (score 3):

[Задачи](http://acm.timus.ru/problemset.aspx) на любой вкус. Заходите, выбираете самую интересную и решаете. По-моему, самый лучший способ изучить (вспомнить) язык - решить несколько задач.

Answer (score 1):

1. Самый главный дзен C++ (после Java/C#) - это деструкторы (`free()` в С).
2. В С/С++ немного заморочена работа со строками - освежи что такое null-terminated строка.
3. Не забывать про размеры типов - в С/С++ это зависит от платформы.
4. Ну и в С/С++ pain конечно отстутствие стандартных библиотек - вернее они для каждой платформы свои
5. В С++ есть еще такая фишка как перегрузка операторов - это ваще жесть, как будто специально сделано для того, чтобы заморочить прогеров.

Comment: 1. Работа с памятью в С++ действительно дело тонкое. Однако вполне решаемая. Есть ряд правил, соблюдая которые, проблем почти не будете иметь.

2. Про класс string не слышали? 

3. Это да, но в общем-то не проблема. 

4. Бред. 

5. Перегрузка операторов - потрясающая вещь. Не надо ее бояться. Это очень мощный и удобный инструмент. Жаль, что ее нет в Java.

Comment: >Ну и в С/С++ pain конечно отстутствие стандартных библиотек - вернее они для каждой платформы свои

Можете привести пример?

Comment: Ну если говорить про <stdio.h> - то вы правы, но согласитесь этого ой как мало. Но давайте заглянем в Symbian C++ - много там стандартных хедеров поддерживаются? Windows Mobile - а там как?

Comment: Во-перых, stdio.h - это больше сишная штука, чем С++. А сравнивать С и Java некоректно. Си - прекрасный процедурный язык для переносимого низкоуровневого программирования. Этим все сказано.

Кстати, после появления STL в комитет по стандартизации С++ пошел поток разных расширений, новых контейнеров, функций, библиотек и т.д. Сначала кое-что приняли, потом престали. В результате возникли независимые коллекции библиотек, расширяющие стандартную, и de facto являющиеся стандартом, например, boost,

Comment: Ну вот опять - начался холивар Java vs. C# vs. C/C++ :)

Comment: Бармалей, пока я вижу только нападения на С/С++ и скромные попытки с их стороны отбить эти нападения )))   У всякого зрелого языка есть своя ниша и свои плюсы и минусы.

Comment: @mikillskegg Я вообще не нападаю - ну как можно нападать на свою первую любовь? Я очень люблю С/С++ (больше наверное С, нежели С++). Иногда приходится брать в руки шашку и вспомнить молодость, но увы все реже и реже. Java заполняет собой все больше и больше пространства, а С уходит куда-то в нишу все глубже и глубже.

Comment: Я много и долго писал на С, причем на очень низкоуровневом С, но в последнее время углубился в С++ и влюбился в разные его штучки: перегрузки разные, шаблоны, STL, boost и прочее. В С++ мне нравится разнообразие и возможность выбора стилей программирования: хочешь, пиши на разных системных вызовах, хочешь, используй удобные обертки и разные шаблоны. А Java как-то не идет у меня. Хотя там ничего нет сложного и все понятно, но... не идет. Слишком много ограничений. Может быть, просто пока не было задач, где она была бы незаменима.